# Get Value from string between ":" and ","

Tags: regex, string, preg-match

Here is example of my string

```
"{"id":128,"order":128,"active":"1","name":"\"
```

Now I need to get "128" - id parameter. So its first value between ":" and ",".

I have tried with preg_match and different regular expressions but I'm just not good in regular expressions. Maybe someone will knew how to make it ?

```
$id = preg_match('/:(,*?)\,/s', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: Why not do `json_decode`?

Comment: It looks like that string is JSON.  Instead of parsing it yourself with regexes, use the json_decode function to decode it into a structure you can access.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: try `preg_match('/(?<=:)[^,]*(?=,)/', $content, $matches);`

Comment: Good idea with json_decode but I don't know why but I have to do it twice to make it StdObject... Its serialized entity to json, once, it is passed to JsonResponse. I make PHPUnit test and when I get this response there I have to do 2 times json_decode to get StdObject... Isn't it weird... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code to get the number after the first `:` using a regex:

```
$re = "/(?<=\\:)[0-9]+/"; 
$str = "\"{\"id\":128,\"order\":128,\"active\":\"1\",\"name\":\"\""; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print $matches[0];
```

Here is a sample program on [TutorialsPoint](http://goo.gl/tq1Ckg).

Just a small detail about this regex `(?<=\\:)[0-9]+`: it uses a fixed-width [look-behind that PHP supports](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php), fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


 $txt='"{"id":128,"order":128,"active":"1","name":"\\"';

 $re1='.*?';    # Non-greedy match on filler
 $re2='(\\d+)'; # Integer Number 1
 $re3='.*?';    # Non-greedy match on filler
 $re4='(\\d+)'; # Integer Number 2
 $re5='.*?';    # Non-greedy match on filler
 $re6='(\\d+)'; # Integer Number 3

   if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6."/is",$txt, $matches))
  {
  $int1=$matches[1][0];
  $int2=$matches[2][0];
  $int3=$matches[3][0];
  print "($int1) ($int2) ($int3) \n";
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: It's not okey, result is Null.